# Text in textview slides down in Android 3.0

Tags: android, textview

I have a RealtiveLayout created in a XML file adjusted for a 480x320 (portrait) view. Everything is created in "dip" units. Basicly it holds 4 textviews that use a quarter of the screen each. They are all positioned by layout_marginLeft and layout_marginTop.
The app has a feature that you can tap on any of these 4 textviews to make it large, and the other 3 will decrease in size and align over each other to the left of the view. Tap the large readout again and all 4 will return to their initial size.

This all works fine on different devices and in the emulator - but not if the emulator runs android 3.0 or higher...

First of all the app doesn't scale, so I made some code that calculates the textview sizes and font size relative to the screen size. This all works beautifully, but in Android 3.0 funny stuff happens once the text gets resized. It suddenly looks as if there is a blank line inserted before the actually text, meaning that I only see the top of the text I want to display.

Here's how the textview is defined. There is a transparent button on top of each readout.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/out1" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:typeface="serif"
android:text="@string/Out1_text" 
android:layout_height="80dip" 
android:layout_width="161dip" 
android:layout_marginLeft="54dip"
android:layout_marginTop="57dip"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:gravity="left|top"
android:maxLines="1"
android:background="#7f7f7f"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/BigButton1" 
android:background="@drawable/transparent" 
android:layout_marginLeft="54dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="57dp" 
android:layout_width="161dp" 
android:layout_height="80dp"/>
```

I've tried different stuff to make sure it's only one line of text, I've set the gravity to top left (even though that's not what I want), but the same thing keep happening.

I change the size and font of the TextView and the button size by this code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(NewOut1Width, NewOut1Height);
params1.setMargins(NewOut1X, NewOut1Y, 0, 0);
big1Button.setLayoutParams(params1);
out1_txtView.setLayoutParams(params1);
out1_txtView.setTextSize(NewOut1FontSize);
```

The "funny" thing is that I call my resizing routine initially, and everything looks alright, once I have made one readout big and then go back to standard size again (with the same values used for the initial display, the text of the textview that was big has moved down one line within the textview.

Does anybody have a clue on what's going on?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**
I've tried to add a getLineBounds, and it show that the baseline of the textView increases as the textSize increases, but it doesn't go down again when the textSize decreases. It doesn't matter if I have gravity top, center or bottom.

Comment: I've got the same problem. My TextView had a background image. The TextViews are in a table in a relative layout. I've removed the image, and the problem seems to have gone away, but I can't be sure yet. It was all working fine for several weeks, then the problem suddenly appeared a after minor, non-related change to another part of the layout (I changed the item at the top from a button, to an ImageView).

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

set the minWidth of the TextView to say 5dp and the layout_width to wrap_content. This would mean that each textView would necessarily occupy 5dp. Also, you dont need to add the gravity since you give the minWidth. And, dont set the width and height of the textView to a static value. Try something like :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
textView.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
```